# Cakephp routing with optional params

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a method in my users controller similar to:

```
function members($type = null, $category = null) { ... }
```

Both params are optional and can be used together or on their own.

So with the following route.

```
Router::connect('/members/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members'));
```

`http://example.com/users/members` successfully becomes `http://example.com/members`.

Unfortunately the following don't work

`http://example.com/members/type:cat`
`http://example.com/members/category:dog`
`http://example.com/members/type:cat/category:dog`

how could I set up my routes so that they all work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named parameters aren't automagicaly mapped to the action. You can either get them by calling

> $this->passedArgs['type'] or $this->passedArgs['category']

or by using the 3rd parameter in the Router::connect:

```
Router::connect(
    '/members/*',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('type', 'category')
    )
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration

Comment: Strangely enough this does work when typing in the url directly although reverse routing does not. $html->link('my link', array('controller' => users, 'action' => 'members', 'type' => 'hello', 'category' => 'world')); results in the regular style url. Is there something else you have to do before reverse routing works?

Comment: are there other routes set up? If so, there is a chance that another connect call takes care of the reverse routing..

Comment: Router::connectNamed(array('type', 'category')); seems to work.

Comment: Can we accomodate a directory name in case controller and views are in some other folder from external routes.php?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
Router::connect('/members/type\:(.*)', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members_type'));
Router::connect('/members/category\:(.*)', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members_category'));
Router::connect('/members/type\:(.*)/category:(.*)', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members_type'));
```

Note that I didn't test it, but I think you must escape the colon.